# Build always fails after testing FileChooser Library

Tags: codenameone

I tested the FileChooser Library with my App - but the iOS-build on the codenameone server failed. Than i added iCloud-Support to the provisioning profile (see attached image) - but the iOS-build still fails. To be able to do any build I removed the FileChooser Library from my project, run "refresh CN1 libs" and cleaned the project. But still the iOS-build fails. I cant' find a snippet of the FileChooser Library in my project any more.

I don't know what to do to get a build again.

In the Log this error is written:

```
Code Signing Error: Provisioning profile "zeitkuenstler_vollversion_development" doesn't include the com.apple.developer.icloud-services entitlement.
warning: skipping file '/var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build8288618829273869413xxx/dist/AppStart-src/AppStart-Info.plist' (unexpected file type 'text.plist.xml' in Frameworks & Libraries build phase)
warning: skipping file '/var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build8288618829273869413xxx/dist/AppStart-src/AppStart-Prefix.pch' (unexpected file type 'sourcecode.c.objc.preprocessed' in Frameworks & Libraries build phase)
Warning: The Link Binary With Libraries build phase contains this target's Info.plist file 'AppStart-src/AppStart-Info.plist'.
Code Signing Error: Code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 11.2'

** ARCHIVE FAILED **
```

**Addition:**
I could solve the problem with adding an iCloud Container to the App-ID in my Apple Developer Account. Before I only used the setting "Compatible with Xcode 5" (see second attached Screenshot).

[image: Screenshot from the Apple Developer Console]

[image]

Comment: Did you redownload and place the new provisioning in the right place? Did you replace both the development and production provisioning? Notice that if you have a build error you don't understand you can submit it to our support engineer in the website (the chat box at the bottom right) and we can help you resolve that issue

Comment: Yes - all the files are freshly downloaded and placed in the right place - I checked this several times. I could solve the problem with adding an iCloud Container to the App-ID in my Apple Developer Account. Before I only used the setting "Compatible with Xcode 5" (see second attached Screenshot). But I'm still wondering why the error could be thrown even the FileChooser-Library is not included in my project?

Comment: Are you sure you removed all the build hints added by the file chooser API? Did you ask the support engineer? I'm guessing without seeing the full error log

Comment: Yes - you are right. There is at least the build-hint ios.icloud.CloudDocuments left.

Comment: That would probably cause that issue. Hopefully this feature would solve these problems in the future https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/2410

Comment: I lost a day trying to figure out why my app won't install anymore. This came after my certificates expired and I had to renew them. I thoght I did something wrong there. But no, this was it. I had to add a container to icloud. Before it worked without a container. Such an unfortunate series of events :(